# How do I count list elements that are not hidden?

Tags: jquery, html, css

Starting with a simple list:

```
<ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li style="display: none;">Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

I know that I can subtract the hidden elements from the list total

```
$('ul li').size() - $('ul li:hidden').size()
```

But I thought there might be a more elegant way to achieve this with jquery:

```
$('ul li:hidden:not').size()
```

That doesn't work.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The opposite of `:hidden` is `:visible` - [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/).

```
$('ul li:visible').size()
```

Comment: If you start on the :hidden page of the docs (http://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/) and click on "Visibility Filter" in the categories in the top right you'll find it. The jQuery docs are very good.

Comment: should use `.length` instead of `.size()`. `size()` has the overhead of a function call where `.length` does not

Answer (score 3):

The simplest form is:

```
var hidden = $("ul > li:hidden").length;
```

On a side note, to correctly use `:not()`:

```
var hidden = $("ul > li:not(:visible)").length;
```

Lastly a jQuery object supports the `size()` method and the `length` property, which are interchangeable.

Comment: Thanks for the help with :not()

I didn't know you could put those sorts of conditions inside of quotes.